# How to set large icons in menu in Vaadin7?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-valo-theme

I'm playing w/ this [Valo theme](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common) sample. In it, when browser screen is widely open i see the menu items as small icon following w/ some text in a singel line. Ok. When i make the browser screen more narrow the menu item look is changing. Now i see larger icon w/ the line of text below it. How can i see such look from the origin? it seems such behavior is related to so called "responsive" design. it is a really cool thing but in this particular case i would like to handle it more precisely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i could find out how to implement what i need. Actually this was a play w/ css selectors. In my case i had to make the following:

```
.v-ui[width-range~="551px-"]
{
  .valo-menu-item
  { 

    .valo-menu-item-wrap
    {
      .v-icon
      {
        display: block;
        /*
          Add anything u need...
        */
      }

      .valo-menu-item-caption
      {
        display: block;
        /*
          Add anything u need...
        */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to modify styles via CSS in your theme that imports the Valo theme. The menu item icons are font icons, so you can just increase the `font-size` via CSS. Inspecting styles of the Valo theme demo with Firefox, I identified the following CSS for the responsive enlargement of the icon:

```
.tests-valo .v-ui.valo-menu-responsive[width-range~="801px-1100px"] .valo-menu-part .valo-menu-item {
    font-size: 26px;
    ...
}
```

More information on responsiveness can be found in [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-responsive.html).

**EDIT** according to the comment:
New line of caption is done by the `display` style.

```
.tests-valo .v-ui.valo-menu-responsive[width-range~="801px-1100px"] .valo-menu-part .valo-menu-item [class*="caption"] {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Steffen! Thanks a lot for your answer but it seems this is not the point( your update only increased the font size but didn't make the label to position itself under the icon( i understand that i have to override the CSS somehow to get the look i need. Now i have to find out how to do it..

Comment: I updated the answer. If you need help to create your own theme, [Vaadin doc](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. here is what i did (just as example): `.v-ui.valo-menu-responsive[width-range~="801px-1100px"] .valo-menu-part .valo-menu-item [class*="caption"] {
    display: block;
    background: red;
  }` This snippet just made a background of menu title red. When browser is open wide - default menu behavior is the same. One more problem is that i support w/ some project theme and can't create another one

Comment: The `[width-range~="801px-1100px"]` means that the style is applied when the browser view port width is in that range. Remove that CSS selector to get the desired effect. You should really read the documentation to get a basic understanding. Regarding the theme: Of course you can add the styles to your existing theme.

Comment: Hi Steffen! it seems i could resolve this issue) Below i added description how... Thanks for assist!

Comment: All right. Please don't forget to mark an answer as answer.